# Resource.Load doesn't load latest files in Unity

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine

I'm using `Resource.Load` to load images of screenshots taken within the game. The player takes a picture (screenshot) which is saved as a png file, this image is then loaded into a GUI box and displayed on screen and can be changed to the next or previous image with the right and left arrows. The images that load into the GUI box though are only ones that exist within the Resources folder before the game is run. This means players can only view images from their last play session and not the current one. I was hoping for some insight as to how to fix the error as I have no idea what's causing it. Any help would be appreciated, code posted below:

Screenshot code:

```
void SavePNG()
{
    Debug.Log("Start Capture");
    picCount += 1;

    var width = Screen.width;
    var height = Screen.height;

    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(width, height, 24);
    cam2.targetTexture = rt;
    cam2.Render();
    RenderTexture.active = rt;

    // Read pixels
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);

    // Clean up
    cam2.enabled = false;
    cam2.targetTexture = null;
    RenderTexture.active = null; // added to avoid errors 
    DestroyImmediate(rt);

    var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    Destroy (tex);     

    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../Assets/Resources/" + picCount + ".png", bytes);

    Debug.Log("Captured");
    Debug.Log("Pic Count: " + picCount);
}
```

GUI Code:

```
public class UserInterface : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Texture ghostPic;

    private int photoList;
    private int photoNum;
    private string photoString;

    int picHeight;
    int picWidth;

    void Start()
    {
        photoNum = Screenshot.picCount;
        photoList = 0;

        picHeight = Screen.height - 160;
        picWidth = 10;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        photoNum = Screenshot.picCount;

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Next") && photoNum > 0)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Next");
            photoList++;

            if(photoList == photoNum + 1)
            {
                photoList = 1;
            }

            Debug.Log("Photo List: " + photoList);

            ChangeImage();
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Last"))
        {
            //Debug.Log("Last");
            photoList--;

            if(photoList == 0)
            {
                photoList = photoNum;
            }

            Debug.Log("Photo List: " + photoList);

            ChangeImage();
        }
    }

    void ChangeImage()
    {
        photoString = photoList.ToString();
        ghostPic = Resources.Load(photoString) as Texture;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(picWidth, picHeight, 300, 150), ghostPic);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time :)

**ETA:**

Ok, so now I'm using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`
to access My Documents. I've tried to write that to a string variable but not sure if that's correct:

`url = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`

But the issue now is that the images are no longer saving to file or loading from file. I've included the new code but it looks like the ChangeImage() function isn't running in the image loader and I have no idea why:

```
void Start()
    {
        url = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

        photoNum = Screenshot.picCount;
        photoList = 0;

        picHeight = Screen.height - 160;
        picWidth = 10;

        photoString = "0";

        ChangeImage();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        photoNum = Screenshot.picCount;

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Next") && photoNum > 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Next");
            photoList++;

            if(photoList == photoNum + 1)
            {
                photoList = 1;
            }

            ChangeImage();
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Last"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Last");
            photoList--;

            if(photoList <= 0)
            {
                photoList = photoNum;
            }

            ChangeImage();
        }

    }

    void ChangeImage()
    {

        photoString = photoList.ToString();
        WWW www = new WWW(url + photoString);

        WaitForLoad();

        if (isDone)
        {
            www.LoadImageIntoTexture(ghostPic);
            Debug.Log("Photo List: " + photoList);
            Debug.Log("Photo String: " + photoString);

            isDone = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForLoad()
    {
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

        isDone = true;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(picWidth, picHeight, 300, 150), ghostPic);
    }
```

I am also using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal`
to save images. Code is same as above with the addition of Environment.Get... etc. and line 28 is now:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(url + picCount + ".png", bytes);
```

I'm assuming I've used this incorrectly but I'm not quite sure how. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm running it through the Unity environment, just scripting in VS.

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add that tag.

Comment: Question updated, thank you

Comment: [This](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/155173-Update-the-resources-folder-at-runtime) might shed some light.  IIRC, resources are packed on build, the folder is just so the editor knows what to pack.  You could use the [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html) class to load your image.

Comment: Little bump for help?

Comment: Bumps don't exist here.  Also please consider closing this question and asking a new one based on your new code.  You no longer use `Resources.Load` but several of us have answered that problem so simply rewording this question is just going to lead to confusion.

Answer (score 0):

All assets stored in a folder named Resources are packed into a single file on build.
That means that `Resources.Load()` requires a path relative to the Resources folder to load the resource, and that the asset name is unique for any other asset in any other Resource folder.

Comment: I am no longer attempting to use Resources.Load() as it doesn't suit my purposes as well as I thought it would. I appreciate your response but I have updated my question to include the most recent form of the code.

Comment: Resource path does not require an extension to work.  Straight from the Unity [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html): `extensions must be omitted`

Comment: @Jerdak, thanks, I've mistaken the `load` call with the `LoadAssetAtPath` which does require extension, I'll fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
url = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
[...]
WWW www = new WWW(url + photoString);
```

`WWW` requires an URI (e.g. `file://home/user/`) , where `Environment.GetFolderPath` returns a file system path (e.g. `/home/user`).

So

```
WWW www = new WWW("file://" + url + photoString);
```

should do the trick. Unless you're on Windows, in which case you would need to do:

```
WWW www = new WWW("file:///" + url + photoString);
```

(Note the three slashes instead of two)

See:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html